# Independence of Gaussian projections

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Suppose  $x=(x_1,x_2)$, whose entries are sampled iid from $N(0,1)$. Let $a=(a_1,a_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $b=(b_1,b_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be two unit vectors such that $a^{\top}b=a_1b_1+a_2b_2=0$.  Let $X=a^{\top}x$ and $Y=b^{\top}x$. Then $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim N(0,1)$. How do we show that $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: Please note $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent even though they are sampled from the same distribution so you can not write $x_1=x_2=x$. It is easy to show $E(XY)=0$. But note that $E(XY)=E(X)\cdot E(Y)$ does not prove $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is likely a homework problem, I won't provide an answer but give suggestions as to how to construct the desired proof.

A standard definition of joint normality of two random variables $W$ and $Z$ is that $W$ and $Z$ are said to be jointly normal if their *linear combination* $\alpha W + \beta Z$ is a normal random variable for all choices of $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$. Choosing $(\alpha,\beta)$ as $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ shows us that when $W$ and $Z$ are jointly normal, they are marginally normal as well.

You have constructed $X$ and $Y$ as *linear combinations* of $X_1$ and $X_2$ and deduced that $X$ and $Y$ are normal random variables, indeed $N(0,1)$ random variables. Can you use the above definition of jointly normal random variables to show that $X$ and $Y$ are *jointly* normal as well? That is, can you write down a proof that every linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ is a normal random variable? Don't shirk this chore: normal random variables are not necessarily *jointly* normal. Once you have proven joint normality of $X$ and $Y$, find $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$, write down the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ and see if it factors into the product of the marginal pdfs of $X$ and $Y$. If so, $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Thank you! This was not a hw problem. I was trying to understand this to solve a related problem for my research. Do you know if the following is a known result?   Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be iid Radamacher random variables and let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a^{\top}b=0$. Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i$ and $Y=\sum_{i=1}^nb_iX_i$. I am interested in  finding the distribution of $X$ conditioned on $Y=c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and eventually show some kind of anti-concentration results along the lines of https://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~pms/files/16.1/Article/16.1.9.pdf.

Comment: @user40739 You should ask a separate question.